# Why is .gitignore not ignoring .DS_Store?

Tags: git, bash

In this case I want to ignore the files iOS uses, and in particular this file

```
.DS_Store
```

I created a .gitignore file as such

```
touch .gitignore
```

and put in a  single line

```
/.DS_Store
```

I push to a bare repo which has a hook to checkout to a full repo.

The file keeps showing up in my full repo.

Comment: The correct entry would be just ".DS_Store". It will also still appear if it is already in your repository.

Comment: have you tried to remove the `cached` copy of a file `git rm --cached path_to_file`?

Comment: That *is* what it is. Like I mentioned in my first comment, if it's already in the repository it will show up even if it is in `.gitignore`.

Comment: This link completely worked for me: https://gist.github.com/lohenyumnam/2b127b9c3d1435dc12a33613c44e6308

Answer (score 60):

You can also remove committed `.DS_Store` files like this: `git rm --cached .DS_Store`

Comment: old Chinese proverb says "and then?"

Answer (score 35):

As you mentioned in your comment, you've already committed the `.DS_Store` file.  To fix this, just remove the file and make a commit.  Then, as long as you have your `.gitignore` file set up and stored in your repo, you shouldn't see any more problems with `.DS_Store` files.